# How do I make a check point for my script? And

Tags: php, curl

Okay, so I am basically making a script to pass post data using cURL. Using my previous example in another question, I will be passing my ever growing list of phone numbers. However, I can only submit 20 phone numbers a day at the max. So how can I make a check point for my script to find out where it last stopped (which phone number was the last submitted)?

Second question, how can I make a "stop" and "start" button? Well technically, it will stop by itself when it hits the max, so how do I make a start button? I guess I can just have a submit button and on click would execute the script. Well, I pretty much answered this question, but I would love to hear more advanced and/or more efficient ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can save the last number in file on disk or better make note of it in database, so you can read it next time, find it and continue from there.

2) you have answered yourself, but you can also make it run as cronjob (automatically on a given date and time)